# Javascript - pass arguments to non-anonymous function

Tags: javascript

I have this function:

```
 $("#btn").click(function(e,someOtherArguments)
   {  //some code
    e.stopPropagation();});
```

It works, but If I have named function I can't use `e` because it is undefined.

```
var namedFunction= function(e,someOtherArguments) 
{
 //some code
  e.stopPropagation();
 }
$("#btn").click(namedFunction(e,someOtherArguments));
```

I would like to use this `namedFunction` because several buttons use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either:

```
$("#btn").click(namedFunction);
```

Or:

```
$("#btn").click(function(e,someOtherArguments){ 

  namedFunction(e, someOtherArguments);

});
```

Comment: +1. Further to this, @impeRAtoR, if you say `$("#btn").click(anyFunction)` jQuery will call `anyFunction()` with the number of arguments it _wants_ to pass, not with the number of arguments you may or may not have declared `anyFunction()` to accept. (Indeed in JS a function doesn't need to explicitly declare named arguments at all since it can access them via the `arguments` object.)

Answer (score 0):

You can call that function directly in the click event

```
$("#btn").click(function(e,someOtherArguments){ 
  namedFunction(e, someOtherArguments);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) like so:

```
$("#btn").click(function(e,someOtherArguments){ 
  namedFunction.apply(this, arguments);
});
```